# SQL : Problems with Subqueries AVG and count

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, average

I'm trying to list all land.name that have more than the average amount of berg associated with it and the amount of bergs.

```
CREATE TABLE Land( 
  c_namn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  code VARCHAR(4) 
);

CREATE TABLE Berg(
  land VARCHAR(4) ,
  Province VARCHAR(50) 
);
```

```
SELECT land.c_name, count(berg.land) 
FROM (
  SELECT avg(a.count3) AS avgberg 
  FROM (
    SELECT count(berg.land) as count3 
    FROM berg) AS a
  ) AS b
  INNER JOIN land ON land.code = berg.land
WHERE a.count3 > b.avgberg
```

When I run my code I get the error message

> "ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"
>   LINE 10: WHERE a.count3 > b.avgberg "

Comment: Why did you nest so many levels of subqueries here?  Can you include sample data which helps to explain your question?

Comment: `a` is inside the second `FROM` clause (defining `b`), that's why it isn't visible "outside". To get help with what you're trying to do edit your question and post the schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements) and the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: `SELECT avg(a.count3) AS avgberg 
  FROM (
    SELECT count(berg.land) as count3 
    FROM berg) AS a` are u missing a group by in the inner subquery here ?? why avg() and count()

Comment: @stickybit I edited and added the relevant information from my relations. How do you propose that I fix the problem with the "invisible" a?

Comment: In your query you use `land.code` yet in your schema description there is no such column. Sample data and desired result is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the problem as this: For each land there are a number of bergs. Find the lands that has more bergs than the average land.
This can be done like this:

```
;WITH bergcount AS
(
    SELECT berg.land, count(berg.land) as count3
    FROM berg
    GROUP BY berg.land
)
SELECT land.name, bergcount.count3
FROM bergcount
INNER JOIN land ON land.code = bergcount.land
WHERE bergcount.count3 >
(
    SELECT avg(count3) as avgberg
    FROM bergcount
)
```

With the new table names that you recently posted the same query will be like this:

```
;WITH bergcount AS
(
    SELECT Berg.land, count(Berg.Land) as count3
    FROM Berg
    GROUP BY Berg.land
)
SELECT Land.name, bergcount.count3
FROM bergcount
INNER JOIN Land ON Land.c_namn = bergcount.land
WHERE bergcount.count3 >
(
    SELECT avg(count3) as avgberg
    FROM bergcount
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get the required results.

```
Select land.name, count(berg.land) 
from land, berg
where land.name = berg.land
group by land.name having count(berg.land) > (SELECT avg(count(berg.land)) as count3 
                                              FROM berg 
                                              group by land) ;
```

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: I tried to apply this but I get the ERROR message "aggregate function calls cannot be nested" from avg(count(berg.land))

Comment: I checked this and it should work. If not in your case you can change the subquery to  SELECT avg(c) as count3 from (select count(berg.land) c, land 
                                              FROM berg group by land )